# Implicit or undefined match object

Tags: python, regex

What I've leaned from working with Python's `re` module is that you always create a `match` object when working with `re` functions

Could someone please explain why and how this piece of code works? I can't get through it.

```
import re

text = "1 < than 2 > 0 & not 'NULL'"

html_escapes = {'&': '&amp;',
                '<': '&lt;',
                '>': '&gt;',
                '"': '&quot;',
                '\'': '&apos;'}


def multiwordreplace(txt, worddict):
    rc = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, worddict)))
    def translate(match):
        return worddict[match.group(0)]
    return rc.sub(translate, txt)

print multiwordreplace(text, html_escapes)
```

Where does this `match` object come from?

Comment: What do you mean with "*comes from?*"

Comment: What i mean is, who or what is creating the `match` object and passes it to `translate`. To me, it looks like it is created on the fly, somehow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = re.compile(a)
x.sub(b, c)
```

is equivalent to

```
re.sub(a, b, c)
```

i.e. the compiled regex `a` is the `pattern`, `b` is the replacement `repl` and `c` is the `string`.

In this case, the `repl` is a *function*, `translate`. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

> If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.

The `match` parameter is supplied by `re.sub` for each match in the `string`, and the function returns the appropriate replacement from `worddict` to substitute into `txt`.

You could also write it as:

```
return rc.sub(lambda match: worddict[match.group(0)], txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you mean where `match` in:

```
def translate(match):
    return worddict[match.group(0)]
```

originates from. Python supports the concept of functional programming where one can pass a function as an argument.

If you thus call `re.sub` as:

```
rc.sub(translate, txt)
```

`translate` is a function. And what `rc.sub` does is looking for matches. **Each match**, one calls the function with a generated argument. The result is the substitute of that function.

Another example is the `map` function:

```
def map(f, lst):
    result = []
    for x in lst:
        result.append(f(x))
    return result
```

Thus what happens is you call `map` **with a function** `f`. Then you iterate over the `lst` and for each element `x`, you **call** `f` with `x`. The result is appended to the list.

You thus don't have to pass `translate` with an argument to get a value, you can pass the function such that another function can call that function with several (different) values itself.